# Get complete GraphQL response using POST without specify field name in request

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

Is there a way to get complete GraphQL response without specifying the Response structure in the request.

i.e. If I need NodeC from path `NodeA/NodeB/NodeC` then need to specific complete path in Request. So my question is if I want to access all node info without specifying any path then how to do that?

My service is POST-GraphQL based.

Comment: You have to specify all the fields you want as part of your request. There is no such thing as a "complete GraphQL response" because recursive types and arguments on individual fields mean there are potentially an infinite number of possible queries.

Comment: ok, then that is a pain. Because there are clients - thin and heavy client. Thin client are interested to get specific data but heavy client want to know all data.